# Listing in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want to check if the index of list in my list is in same position, then after make the position same I want to print it

```
news_a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
news_b = ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
for i in news_a:
    for j in news_b:
        if i == j:
            print(f"{i}\n{j}")
```

Comment: `for i in news_a` will iterate over the _values_ of the list, so `i` will be `'A'`, `'B'`, and so on. it will not give you indices.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to ask. For the given input, what should the exact output be? (If that output is not interesting, edit the input so that you can have output that explains what the code is supposed to do.)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what exactly you mean by "index of the list"? The code you have is just going through both arrays of strings and checks each string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Please [edit] to clarify what you're trying to accomplish exactly. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](/q/1663807/4518341)

Comment: You should clarify what you want to achieve, but look up `enumerate` and `list.index`, and I think you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, all you have to change is that you need to reference the **index** of each element in your for-loop iterations, and the elements themselves when printing them.

```
news_a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
news_b = ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
for i in range(len(news_a)):
    for j in range(len(news_b)):
        if i == j:
            print(f"{news_a[i]}\n{news_b[j]}")
```

Comment: well thanks for the answer